# Relating VBA to Python

Tags: python, library, vba

I'm new to python. The last programming language learnt is VBA. I know that with python you can import libraries or module such as the requests, math, and selenium. VBA has a tool called the object browser where you can explore a library classes/objects, members of a class, and properties. Is this capable in python also? If so, how do I access it? This would be helpful in learning and exploring all the capabilities that come with an imported python library/module. Any similar tools to this would be great!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than a graphical explorer python provides 2 commands in interactive sessions `dir` and `help` these can be used respectively to see what methods are available and to view the documentation on them, *note that some  packages provide more than others.*

So in an interactive session you can do:
[image]

I would suggest installing ipython - *this can be done with `pip install ipython` from the command line.* This adds to the interactive session, *amongst many other things*:

- Tab Completion *Typing part of something then pressing the tab key will show you possible completions*
  [image]
- Fast help with `?` *Adding ? after something displays the help*
  [image]
- Source display with `??` *Adding ?? after something displays the source code*
  [image]

The Python documentation is online and available for download and is excellent. There is also the pydoc [document generator & help system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html) supplied with python. It can be used:

- To display help on a module in the command prompt with: *path_to_python*\Lib\pydoc.py *module_name*
- To start a web server and open a browser window with: *path_to_python*\Lib\pydoc.py -b
- To start a web server with: *path_to_python*\Lib\pydoc.py -n